# How to fix Ruby gem bundler installation?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

Looks like bundler is installed in my machine but I am getting an error while I run `bundle -v`.

**Error:**

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 71 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure about what's wrong!

**Update:**

I was unable to find bundler from `gem list`

When I run `which bundle`, I see the output as `/usr/local/bin/bundle` and in that location I see `bundle` and `bundler` executables.

When I run `sudo gem install bundler`, I get the below error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

Comment: That's your system Ruby. Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm`?

Comment: Also, how do you know that bundler is installed?

Comment: `gem list bundler` to see if it's there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by disabling System Integrity Protection.

To disable SIP restart your MAC in recovery mode by holding Command+R and open terminal from utilities and running `csrutil disable`.

Comment: or just run `gem install bundler` omitting the prefix `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

First lets see the basic questions.

Who is the owner of  /usr/local? Change to your user

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Did you type "bundle" update? if you have bundle installed.

```
bundle update
```

If you don't have bundler installed, install:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rbenv you will need to run

`rbenv rehash`

---

I ran into this exact problem after setting my global rbenv and sourcing from my bash profile like below.

`vi ~/.bash_profile`

**Insert these two lines**

`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`

**Source ruby to look rbenv instead of the system ruby**

`source ~/.bash_profile`

**Ran into error here**

**Run rehash**

`rbenv rehash`

**Problem Solved**